# Why ng-show is not working properly?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I developing a web application using asp.net mvc 5 and angularjs. Im wondering why the ng-show is not working or not showing the message.

angularjs code:

```
 vm.checkEmailFormat = function () {
        var email = $(".pv-company-email").val();

        var regex = /^[\w-]+(\.[\w-]+)*@([a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*?\.[a-z]{2,6}|(\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3})(:\d{4})?$/i;

        vm.validEmailFormat = (regex.test(email));

        if (vm.validEmailFormat) {
            vm.pageValidated = true;
        } else {
            vm.pageValidated = false;
        }
    }
```

view code:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-3 settings-padding"><span class="textdescription"><strong>Email Address</strong></span></div>
  <div class="col-md-6 settings-padding">
    <input type="text" ng-model="vm.organisation.Email" ng-blur="vm.checkIsEmailBlank()" ng-keyup="vm.checkEmailFormat()" placeholder="Email" class="form-control comp pv-company-email" style="max-width:420px;" maxlength="250" />
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3 settings-padding"><span class="error company-error" ng-show="!vm.validEmailFormat"><span class="company-border-top"><i class="fa fa-times-circle ngdialog-register-erroricon" aria-hidden="true"></i></span> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Invalid email format.</span>
  </div>
  @*
  <div class="col-md-3 settings-padding"><span class="error company-error" ng-show="vm.isEmailEmpty"><span class="company-border-top"><i class="fa fa-times-circle ngdialog-register-erroricon" aria-hidden="true"></i></span> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Email is required.</span>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3 settings-padding"><span class="error company-error" ng-show="vm.validEmailLength"><span class="company-border-top"><i class="fa fa-times-circle ngdialog-register-erroricon" aria-hidden="true"></i></span> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Must be 50 characters long only.</span>
  </div>*@

</div>
```

Comment: You can do this in your controller **var vm = this;**

Answer (score 3):

In view you have to use `<input type="text" ng-model="controllerAliseName.organisation.Email" ng-blur="controllerAliseName.checkIsEmailBlank()" ng-keyup="controllerAliseName.checkEmailFormat()" placeholder="Email" class="form-control comp pv-company-email" style="max-width:420px;" maxlength="250" />`
Insetad of `vm.`,and you need to make `vm.isEmailEmpty` flag true once you find `ng-model="controllerAliseName.organisation.Email"` is empty on blur function. You are not checking condition

Answer (score 0):

Here you need to apply variable changes in view.
Try following:

```
if (vm.validEmailFormat) {
    $scope.$apply(function () {
        vm.pageValidated = true;
    });
}
else{
    $scope.$apply(function () {
        vm.pageValidated = false;
    })
}
```